# How to wire an entire room / kitchen with LED light strips?

Tags: wiring, led

As the question suggests, I'm looking into adding LED light strips throughout the kitchen (over cabinet, under cabinet, and kick -- I think under the countertop would be neat, but harder to hide). From what I have been reading, I realize that to more accurately determine what is needed that I would need to know specifics about the lights (like wattage, amperage, run lengths, LEDs per foot/meter).

But without knowing those specifics yet, to try to better understand how feasible this is, here is my intended setup. The kitchen has cabinets on opposite walls, with an island in the middle, something like this (where the square brackets represent cabinets and the island):

```
[]  []  []
[]  []  []
[]  []  []
[]______[]
```

Is it possible to have everything wired together on one circuit, even though there's about 15' from one side of the kitchen to the other? Am I able to run a wire (maybe 16/5 -- thinking of using RGBW) under the floor/ceiling to get to the other side and then hook up the strips without worrying about voltage drop? I'm sure this is possible, I just don't want to spend a fortune to make it work.

As a side question, if anyone knows, is there such thing as a on/off/motion switch, that also works with wifi (for use with Google Assistant / Alexa)? The thought would be I could turn the lights on or off, or to a motion mode that detects presence in the room.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of feet, but your correct about your voltage drop worry.  My .02 cents: think about using multiple transformers (each area has its own) feeding multiple [zigbee controllers](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07FTD9H7T/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_i_Gw1VCbTWSGG9B) and a Hue bridge (compatible with my link) to control the multiple controllers as a single zone.  Oh yea..  upgrade from RGBW to RGB+CCT strips too... the difference is the color temperature of white is adjustable.

Comment: Actually my link above is NOT what I intended to link.  [This](https://www.amazon.com/Gledopto-Zigbee-Strip-Controller-DC12-24v/dp/B07QBM2456) is the controller that Is listed as compatible with the Hue bridge. (The first one might be but [Glendopto](https://iconnecthue.com/supported-devices/) definitely is listed by Hue.)

Comment: unless they are driven hot, 15' should be ok with a connection on only one end, though it's close to the 5 meter limit. if practical, you can feed both ends at the same time, in parallel, or the ground on one end and vcc on the other, so that one end isn't dimmer, and the ramp-down is halved (compared to single-ended). As far was wifi/PIR control, there's a bevy of options, even at home depot. 16awg@110AC (or even 12vDC) is plenty for the supply, overkill in fact.